# Managing team's computers

Tags: macos

I need to manage my team's computers (which are iMacs) but I'm not sure how.
I need to prevent a user from changing his root password, or to navigate on a given website, etc.
If possible, I would also need to monitor a computer's activity, and remotely retrieve its hardware setup.

Is there any clean and easy way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is software called 'Jamf'.